# Passing a Class object to a function in Objective C - with restrictions on the classes that it represents?

Tags: objective-c, class

(I probably didn't phrase that very well!)

I'd like to pass a Class object into an Objective C function:

```
-(void)someMethod:(Class *)classObject { ...
```

And, if I want to restrict the parameter to classes who implement a particular protocol, I know I can do this:

```
-(void)someMethod:(Class<SomeProtocol> *)classObject { ...
```

But is it possible to do the same for Classes instead of Protocols?

To use the classic "I have a Dog class which extends Animal" example, can I restrict the parameter to accept [Animal class] and [Dog class], but not [Cheese class]?

Thanks in advance!
 Matthew

Comment: it should be just `Class`, not `Class *`. `Class` is already an object pointer type. `Class *` will not work as you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it at compile time. `Class` is a type, it's the same type returned from both `[Animal class]` and `[Cheese class]` so the compiler will never complain. If you want, you could restrict it at runtime; you could throw an invalid argument exception if the wrong type of class was provided.

```
- (void) someMethod:(Class *) classObject
{
    if (![classObject isSubclassOfClass:[Animal class]])
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException
                    format:@"Wanted an Animal but got %@", NSStringFromClass(classObject)];

    // do whatever.
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks folks! I come from a Java background, so wanted something similar to Java's "Class<Animal>" generic type notation.

Comment: `classObject` should have type `Class` not `Class *`